# Show div when input is checked, CSS-only no javascript

Tags: css

I have a form where if someone checks a specific input, I want it to show a div. The problem is that the input does not share the same parent as the subsequent div (and can't, for framework reasons). So for example:

```
<div>
    <input id="test" type="radio">
</div>
<div id="ShowIfTestIsChecked">
    <!--content to show if test input is checked-->
</div>
```

This CSS almost works, but is broken by the fact that the div I want to show is not inside the parent of the input:

```
#test ~ #ShowIfTestIsChecked{
    display:none;
}
#test:checked ~ #ShowIfTestIsChecked{
    display:block;
}
```

Is there some other CSS trick I can use here to make this work? This is easy to do with javascript, but I'd like a CSS only way to do it.

Comment: the only way to do this would be to make the input be a sibling of the div you want to show / hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in css would require being able to select the parents div and then the next div which isn't possible in css, You can only select the next or children elements in a css selector.

Why do you want to wrap the input in a div in the first place?

Gimme a sec I'll post an update with css trick that works they way you want but requires changing the first div element into a form element.

So you have to chance the html or us js.

For html you've got 2 options , put the content of each div together or use a form element:

```
<form>
    <input id="trick" type="radio" name="trick" required />
</form>
<div id="ShowIfTestIsChecked">
    Hello world
</div>
```

```
#ShowIfTestIsChecked {
    display: none;
}

form:valid ~ #ShowIfTestIsChecked {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Would be really convenient if we could select parent elements in CSS! That's a clever trick with the form element, but probably not any better than just using javascript

Comment: The :valid selector is usefull to hide the submit button till everything is filled in as example.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your checkbox and div together:

```
<input id="test" type="radio">
<div id="ShowIfTestIsChecked"></div>

#test:checked ~ #ShowIfTestIsChecked {
    display: block;
}
```

There's no other CSS-way.

Comment: Nah it can also be done by replacing the first ``<div>`` with a ``<form>`` element.

Comment: As I indicated in the question, I already knew this would work. Unfortunately I can't take the input out of the containing div because the framework I'm using requires that it have it's own containing element.

Comment: @Matthew apparently you'll have to use JS